# recover data from broken Xiaomi phone when usb debugging in turned off

Tags: android, mobile, xiaomi, miui

Hello guys my phone screen is broke and i cannot control it , i need get my photos and vidios
I try to google the problem but all answers i get need to enable debugging mode
is there a way to have the photos in my case.
my device is redmi note 8.

Comment: It would be easier to fix the screen

Comment: The question should be posted in [Android Enthusiast](https://android.stackexchange.com/)